# emitting the ti sensor tag data on websocket in Node red

Tags: websocket, sensors, node-red

I am using node red and TI sensor tag. I want to emit sensor data on websocket using websocket node of node red.
Any help how I can send sensor data on websocket in node-red.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Data form your TI SensorTag can be received in Node-RED through the ibmiot node. Its msg.payload holds the sensor data from your device (once configured). What you could do then, connect that node to a function node to modify the data and its formatting and hand it over to a websocket output node.

In the [Node-RED flow library](http://flows.nodered.org/) are some flows making use of websockets. I recommend looking there for creative input. [This example uses data from a Raspberry PI and sends it to a websocket](http://flows.nodered.org/flow/f9520d048cb7ccb9e40a).